# Connecting to TFS 2008 database from Business Intelligence Studio 2005

Tags: tfs, bids, tfs-2008

This is a beginner question, I have to create some SQL Reports with business intelligence Studio 2005, but I don't have any idea how to connect to the TFS server 2008 Database.
These are my doubts:

1. how to get the TFS DB server name, whether this will be different from TFS server name.
2. What all user permissions are required for working with the DB and which database of TFS 2008 should i connect to.
3. Whether Business Intelligence Studio 2005 supports creating reports for TFS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal TFS 2008 installation consists of multiple DBs on a single SQL Server. For the name of that SQL instance you need to ask your administrator.

For reports you want to use the TfsWarehouse DB. This DB also feeds a SSAS cube (again, ask your admin for the instance name), which can also be used for reports.

You need read permissions (data_reader on SQL Server) on one or both to create reports against it. Using BI Studio 2005 should not be a hindrance.

A word of caution: The warehouse structure has changed significantly with TFS 2010, so your reports will require some rework when you change.

Check out [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/teams_wit_tools/archive/tags/reporting/) for additional info on custom TFS reports and the warehouse structrure.